# How can I get odd numbered characters in a string using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, substring

I am playing with some encrypted data and I need to get the odd numbered characters from a string and populate into a column:

```
abcedfgh
```

to

```
acdg
```

Is it really possible to do it in SQL? I tried googling on this but couldn't find any search results.

Comment: What do you mean by odd numbered chars? Could you post an example?

Comment: You mean every other character from the string, i.e., index = 1, 3, 5, ... ?

Comment: Yes I need all characters with 1,3,5 indexes...

Comment: Why the downvotes? It's a pretty valid question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(mycolumn, '(.).', '\1')
FROM   mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT REPLACE(DATA,',','') MYDATA
FROM(
      SELECT WM_CONCAT(DATA) AS  DATA
      FROM (
            SELECT SUBSTR('abcedfgh',LEVEL,1) DATA,ROWNUM RN
            FROM DUAL 
            CONNECT BY LEVEL <=LENGTH('abcedfgh')

           )
      WHERE MOD(RN,2) =1
    )
```